# Use NPOI to read string value of all cells in a row in xlsx file, including merge cell

Tags: c#, excel

I'm currently using NPOI library to read the value of all cells in one row of a xlsx file and return a `List<string>`. However, if a cell is part of a merged cell, then I need to get the value of that merged cell instead of a blank value. (In NPOI, if a cell is part of a merged cell but is not the top-most and left-most cell in that merged region, then when using `FormatCellValue` on that cell, we got a empty string).

Let say that I have already retrieved the necessary row and get an `IRow` object, and there is no empty cell at the left of this row. Also, my data will always be `string`, there will be no other data type.

This is what I came up with:

```
private List<string> readRow(IRow row)
{
    var rs = new List<string>();

    // Since there would be no emtpy cell, 
    // we start from the left-most cell and read until the end.
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < row.LastCellNum; colIndex++)
    {
        var cell = row.GetCell(colIndex);

        // Get the value of this cell, whether it is part of a merged cell or not.
        var cellValue = getCellValue(cell);

        rs.Add(cellValue);
    }
    return rs;
}
```

And the method to get cell value:

```
private string getCellValue(ICell cell)
{
    var dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    // If this is not part of a merge cell,
    // just get this cell's value like normal.
    if (!cell.IsMergedCell)
    {
        return dataFormatter.FormatCellValue(cell);
    }

    // Otherwise, we need to find the value of this merged cell.
    else
    {          
        // Get current sheet.
        var currentSheet = cell.Sheet;

        // Loop through all merge regions in this sheet.
        for (int i = 0; i < currentSheet.NumMergedRegions; i++)
        {
            var mergeRegion = currentSheet.GetMergedRegion(i);

            // If this merged region contains this cell.
            if (mergeRegion.FirstRow <= cell.RowIndex && cell.RowIndex <= mergeRegion.LastRow &&
                mergeRegion.FirstColumn <= cell.ColumnIndex && cell.ColumnIndex <= mergeRegion.LastColumn)
            {
                // Find the top-most and left-most cell in this region.
                var firstRegionCell = currentSheet.GetRow(mergeRegion.FirstRow)
                                        .GetCell(mergeRegion.FirstColumn);

                // And return its value.
                return dataFormatter.FormatCellValue(firstRegionCell);
            }
        }
        // This should never happen.
        throw new Exception("Cannot find this cell in any merged region");
    }
}
```

I was surprised to find that there is no simpler way to get value of merged cell using NPOI. What can I improve here?